Struggling to start a service from cloud-init
I have an application thats bootstrapped into my VM images, then then Cloud-init runs a script to create a service.
My issue is - if I run it in cloud init, it appears too early, and needs restarting before it will work.
I tried to have it need cloud init to finish, but then that gets stuck in a dependency loop, as Cloud Init won't finish till the service is started.
Have I missed something? Unless I start the service, the below method just leaves it enabled and never actually starts.
app.service - app
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/app.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

Cloud init script:
- systemctl enable /usr/local/bin/app/app.service
Service file:
[Unit]
Description=App
#only run after cloud-init
After=cloud-final.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /usr/local/bin/app/app.js
Restart=always
DynamicUser=yes
Group=nogroup
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/bin/app/
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=middleware

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


The issue you're encountering a race condition between your application service and the cloud-init process. Since cloud-init isn't finishing before your service starts, the service is stuck in an "inactive" state, but enabling the service doesn't actually start it.
